# How to select weekends with flot using selection plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, selection, flot

The goal:
To get selected weekends highlighted, for selected week for example the good people at wordpress  did exactly what i am trying to do here is an image [image]

They are using the same plugin that I am using located [here](https://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.selection.js?r=220), I looked through the source code at there [github page](https://github.com/Automattic/Jetpack)  but no luck. a lot of the files got renamed to wordpress convention which makes it a bit tricky to navigate.

What i got completed:
I can select any date range using

```
plot.setSelection({ 
    xaxis: {
        from: 0, to: 2 
    }
});
```

But I am not able to select multiple weekends. I have the array from the back-end code returning the selected weekends, I am not sure how to let the plugin know how to accept the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for markings:

```
grid: 
{
    markings: [
        { xaxis: { from:  2, to: 4 }, color: "#eeeeee" },
        { xaxis: { from:  8, to: 12 }, color: "#eeeeee" }
    ]
}
```